# Divio application freezes and stops working

Tags: divio

I have installed the Divio app on Windows 10 according to the documentation.

The app appears to start well, but when I select a project and hit **Set-up project**, logs are displayed, but then the application appears to freeze.

I am running the app as administrator.

Comment: Can you provide the logs you see? And can you confirm whether you are using Windows 10 Pro?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in:
I have choose custom project directorie so I have to select in Docker : 
settings-> shared drives and chose drive where is my project. 
[Read more in Divio Academy](http://support.divio.com/local-development/docker/how-to-use-a-directory-outside-cusers-with-docker-toolboxdocker-for-windows)